# I like to have the dropdown to right or left based on the screen size | materil-ui, Autocomplete, Popper

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, autocomplete

I like to display the dropdown left as default but the screen view gets smaller, the dropdown aligns right.

This should what looks like as default.
[image]

When the page gets smaller, it should look like this.
[image]

How can I do that?

Here is the [Autocomplete component](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/autocomplete/)

```
import * as React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";

import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";
import Autocomplete from "@mui/material/Autocomplete";
import Popper from "@mui/material/Popper";

export const LabelPopper = styled(({ ...props }) => (
  <Popper {...props} placement="bottom-end" />
))`
  .MuiAutocomplete-paper {
    width: 300px;
    margin-top: 4px;
    box-shadow: 0px 14.3544px 28.7089px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04),
      0px 2.87089px 8.61266px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04),
      0px 0px 1.43544px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  }
`;

export default function ComboBox() {
  const renderOptionHelper = (props, option, state) => {
    return (
      <div sx={{ width: 300 }}>
        <li>{option.label}</li>
      </div>
    );
  };
  return (
    <div style={{ margin: "100px" }}>
      <Autocomplete
        disablePortal
        open
        id="combo-box-demo"
        options={top100Films}
        renderInput={(params) => (
          <TextField sx={{ width: 200 }} {...params} label="Movie" />
        )}
        renderOption={renderOptionHelper}
        PopperComponent={LabelPopper}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

// Top 100 films as rated by IMDb users. http://www.imdb.com/chart/top
const top100Films = [
  { label: "The Shawshank Redemption", year: 1994 },
  { label: "The Godfather", year: 1972 },
  { label: "The Godfather: Part II", year: 1974 },
  { label: "The Dark Knight", year: 2008 },
  { label: "12 Angry Men", year: 1957 },
  { label: "Schindler's List", year: 1993 },
  { label: "Pulp Fiction", year: 1994 },
  {
    label: "The Lord of the Rings: The Return of the King",
    year: 2003
  },
  { label: "The Good, the Bad and the Ugly", year: 1966 },
  { label: "Fight Club", year: 1999 },
  {
    label: "The Lord of the Rings: The Fellowship of the Ring",
    year: 2001
  },
  {
    label: "Star Wars: Episode V - The Empire Strikes Back",
    year: 1980
  },
  { label: "Forrest Gump", year: 1994 },
  { label: "Inception", year: 2010 },
  {
    label: "The Lord of the Rings: The Two Towers",
    year: 2002
  },
  { label: "One Flew Over the Cuckoo's Nest", year: 1975 },
  { label: "Goodfellas", year: 1990 },
  { label: "The Matrix", year: 1999 },
  { label: "Seven Samurai", year: 1954 },
  {
    label: "Star Wars: Episode IV - A New Hope",
    year: 1977
  },
  { label: "City of God", year: 2002 },
  { label: "Se7en", year: 1995 },
  { label: "The Silence of the Lambs", year: 1991 },
  { label: "It's a Wonderful Life", year: 1946 },
  { label: "Life Is Beautiful", year: 1997 },
  { label: "The Usual Suspects", year: 1995 },
  { label: "Léon: The Professional", year: 1994 },
  { label: "Spirited Away", year: 2001 },
  { label: "Saving Private Ryan", year: 1998 },
  { label: "Once Upon a Time in the West", year: 1968 },
  { label: "American History X", year: 1998 },
  { label: "Interstellar", year: 2014 },
  { label: "Casablanca", year: 1942 },
  { label: "City Lights", year: 1931 },
  { label: "Psycho", year: 1960 },
  { label: "The Green Mile", year: 1999 },
  { label: "The Intouchables", year: 2011 },
  { label: "Modern Times", year: 1936 },
  { label: "Raiders of the Lost Ark", year: 1981 },
  { label: "Rear Window", year: 1954 },
  { label: "The Pianist", year: 2002 },
  { label: "The Departed", year: 2006 },
  { label: "Terminator 2: Judgment Day", year: 1991 },
  { label: "Back to the Future", year: 1985 },
  { label: "Whiplash", year: 2014 },
  { label: "Gladiator", year: 2000 },
  { label: "Memento", year: 2000 },
  { label: "The Prestige", year: 2006 },
  { label: "The Lion King", year: 1994 },
  { label: "Apocalypse Now", year: 1979 },
  { label: "Alien", year: 1979 },
  { label: "Sunset Boulevard", year: 1950 },
  {
    label:
      "Dr. Strangelove or: How I Learned to Stop Worrying and Love the Bomb",
    year: 1964
  },
  { label: "The Great Dictator", year: 1940 },
  { label: "Cinema Paradiso", year: 1988 },
  { label: "The Lives of Others", year: 2006 },
  { label: "Grave of the Fireflies", year: 1988 },
  { label: "Paths of Glory", year: 1957 },
  { label: "Django Unchained", year: 2012 },
  { label: "The Shining", year: 1980 },
  { label: "WALL·E", year: 2008 },
  { label: "American Beauty", year: 1999 },
  { label: "The Dark Knight Rises", year: 2012 },
  { label: "Princess Mononoke", year: 1997 },
  { label: "Aliens", year: 1986 },
  { label: "Oldboy", year: 2003 },
  { label: "Once Upon a Time in America", year: 1984 },
  { label: "Witness for the Prosecution", year: 1957 },
  { label: "Das Boot", year: 1981 },
  { label: "Citizen Kane", year: 1941 },
  { label: "North by Northwest", year: 1959 },
  { label: "Vertigo", year: 1958 },
  {
    label: "Star Wars: Episode VI - Return of the Jedi",
    year: 1983
  },
  { label: "Reservoir Dogs", year: 1992 },
  { label: "Braveheart", year: 1995 },
  { label: "M", year: 1931 },
  { label: "Requiem for a Dream", year: 2000 },
  { label: "Amélie", year: 2001 },
  { label: "A Clockwork Orange", year: 1971 },
  { label: "Like Stars on Earth", year: 2007 },
  { label: "Taxi Driver", year: 1976 },
  { label: "Lawrence of Arabia", year: 1962 },
  { label: "Double Indemnity", year: 1944 },
  {
    label: "Eternal Sunshine of the Spotless Mind",
    year: 2004
  },
  { label: "Amadeus", year: 1984 },
  { label: "To Kill a Mockingbird", year: 1962 },
  { label: "Toy Story 3", year: 2010 },
  { label: "Logan", year: 2017 },
  { label: "Full Metal Jacket", year: 1987 },
  { label: "Dangal", year: 2016 },
  { label: "The Sting", year: 1973 },
  { label: "2001: A Space Odyssey", year: 1968 },
  { label: "Singin' in the Rain", year: 1952 },
  { label: "Toy Story", year: 1995 },
  { label: "Bicycle Thieves", year: 1948 },
  { label: "The Kid", year: 1921 },
  { label: "Inglourious Basterds", year: 2009 },
  { label: "Snatch", year: 2000 },
  { label: "3 Idiots", year: 2009 },
  { label: "Monty Python and the Holy Grail", year: 1975 }
];
```

##### Attempts

I added `placement="bottom-end"` on  `<Popper {...props} placement="bottom-end" />` but that seems not working.